# OpenVPN fails to start with error "could not execute external program"

Tags: 12.04, networking, vpn, openvpn

I've been banging my head against the wall for several hours now and I'm at my wits end. I've double checked my setup against numerous guides and it checks out, but OpenVPN still fails to start. The sticking point seems to revolve around my "up" script, and something about failing to execute an external program. I've been scouring Google for people with similar issues, but none of them seemed related.

**System:**
An old Ubuntu 12.04 home server that I've been using for SSH Tunneling and file serving. It connects via Wi-Fi to my router due to physical limitations.

**Note:**
Initial setup was done by [OpenVPN-Install script](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install).

#### /var/log/syslog:

```
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11
    ] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Dec  1 2014
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: IMPORTANT: OpenVPN's default port number is now 1194, bas
ed on an official port number assignment by IANA.  OpenVPN 2.0-beta16 and earlier used 5000 as the defa
ult port.
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: WARNING: --ping should normally be used with --ping-resta
rt or --ping-exit
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow thi
s configuration to call user-defined scripts
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: WARNING: file 'static.key' is group or others accessible
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Static Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Static Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Static Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Static Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: WARNING: normally if you use --mssfix and/or --fragment, you should also set --tun-mtu 1500 (currently it is 1200)
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: /sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.1.0.1 pointopoint 10.1.0.2 mtu 1200
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* NetworkManager[1154]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* NetworkManager[1154]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: /etc/openvpn/office.up tun0 1200 1244 10.1.0.1 10.1.0.2 init
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): could not execute external program
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* ovpn-openvpn[5084]: Exiting
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* avahi-daemon[1162]: Withdrawing workstation service for tun0.
Jul 27 18:53:01 ************* NetworkManager[1154]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
```

#### openvpn.conf:

```
dev tun
# Network interface used by the VPN server on WIFI_SUBNET
# eth1 (192.168.1.1) in the previous example
local 192.168.1.4
# The following line defines two new VPN interfaces
# ifconfig VPN_SERVER VPN_CLIENT
ifconfig 10.1.0.1 10.1.0.2
script-security 3
up /etc/openvpn/office.up
secret static.key
ping 15
tun-mtu 1200
mssfix 1400
verb 3
```

#### server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

#### office.up:

```
# office.up
#!/bin/sh
route add -net 10.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $5
```

Comment: Sorry to ask the 'obvious' question, but is the `office.up` script executable? Also have you tried including the full path to the route command (probably `/sbin/route`)?

Comment: Does it make sense to try embedding the contents of office.up in openvpn.conf instead of calling an external script file? I have a working openvpn setup but I don't call external scripts from the config file.

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah the script is executable, I tried 0777 to make sure as a test, but it didn't help. Haven't tried full pathing route.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Not sure how to embed the up script in the conf, not familiar with the syntax that would be needed.